# Is there an existing way to add a comma between elements of a Scan?

Tags: list-manipulation

Without thinking, I wrote (the equivalent of) this...

```
output = "";
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Scan[(output = output <> ToString[#] <> ",") &, list];
output

(* actual "1,2,3,4,5," *)

(* desired "1,2,3,4,5" *)
```

`Riffle` and `StringRiffle` won't work for me - I need an approach that works with side-effect functions.

I could write my own if I had to (see below), but **am I missing some existing approach**?

```
scanBetween[f1_, f0Between_, list_] := Module[{i},
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++, (
      If[i > 1, f0Between[]];
      f1[list[[i]]];
      )];
   ];

output = "";
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
scanBetween[(output = output <> ToString[#]) &, (output = 
    output <> ",") &, list]
output

(* "1,2,3,4,5" *)
```

**Edited**

This seems a little better - it uses an existing function, but is still not completely straightforward...

```
output = "";
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
addOutput[v_] := output = output <> ToString[v];
MapIndexed[
  Function[{each, i}, If[First@i > 1, addOutput[","]]; 
   addOutput[each]], list];
output

(* "1,2,3,4,5" *)
```

Comment: Yes, but I think I simplified my real problem too much.  These are all good solutions to the problem I stated, but I need one that works by calling functions, not by "assembling" something...  I'm building a very simple recursive parser, but it was too big to show here.  I added a second approach above.

Comment: With this many responses, you have collectively answered my question.  There seems to be no built-in command for what I am doing.  Riffle and StringRiffle solve this type of problem in a functional way, and my side-effect situation is both rare enough, and non-Wolfram enough, to not warrant a built-in solution.  I am choosing the mainstream solution as the answer for this page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StringRiffle` (added in V10.1) will do this, and even does the conversion from numbers to strings:

```
In[5]:= StringRiffle[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ","]

Out[5]= "1,2,3,4,5"
```

Comment: The question says that `Riffle` and `StringRiffle` don't work for the particular situation.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that this should work:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
output = ToString@Row[list, ","]

(* Out: "1,2,3,4,5" *)
```

Comment: He wants to use it inside `Scan` where he only has access to one element at a time. This solution presupposes access to all elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a function that will modify itself after first usage.

```
commaFromSecondUsage[] := (commaFromSecondUsage[] = ","; "")

output = "";
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Scan[(output = output <> commaFromSecondUsage[] <> ToString[#]) &, list];
output
(* "1,2,3,4,5" *)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you return an anonymous function from a `Module` then that function will encapsulate the local variables in that `Module`. This can be used here like this:

```
newCharacterStream[] := Module[{str = ""},
  StringTrim[str = StringJoin[str, #, ","], ","..] &
  ]

str = newCharacterStream[];
str["test"]; str["test2"]; str["test3"]
```

This returns `"test,test2,test3"`. You can easily create a new string concatenation object, and it will be completely independent of the previous instance:

```
str2 = newCharacterStream[];
str2["t"]; str2["t2"]; str2["t3"]
```

This will return `"t,t2,t3"`. If you only need one object you can change `:=` to `=` and just set `str = Module[...]`.

You can retrieve the string without appending to it by evaluating `str[""]`.

The approach described here has the advantage that it encapsulates variables so they don't pollute the global namespace. But honestly if you are not worried about that, I don't see why the first solution that you propose shouldn't work. Just make sure to apply `StringTrim` to the string before you use it.

Answer (score 2):

I still think the best solution is to use `StringRiffle`, but to use it in concert with [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).

```
In[1]:= Replace[
         Reap[
          Scan[Sow@*ToString, list],
          _, StringRiffle[#2, ","] &],
         {{Null, {result_}} :> result,
          _ -> ""}]
Out[2]= "1,2,3,4,5"
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on your code, where the logic is built into `addOutput`:

```
output = "";
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

addOutput[v_] /; output === "" := output = ToString[v];
addOutput[v_] := output = output <> "," <> ToString[v];

Scan[Function[{each}, addOutput[each]], list];

output

(*
==> "1,2,3,4,5"
*)
```